# Java Swing Message Dialog remove line at GTK look and feel

Tags: java, swing, gtk

I'm displaying this dialog:

```java
String connectingDialogTitle = "Connexió amb el servidor";
String connectingDialogMessage = "S'està establint la connexió amb el servidor";
ImageIcon connectingDialogIcon = new ImageIcon("client/src/main/resources/assets/gui/loading.gif");

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                windowComponent, connectingDialogMessage, connectingDialogTitle,
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, connectingDialogIcon)
);
```

With the Metal look and feel (the default for me) looks like this:

[image]

But with the GTK look and feel looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove that ugly line that appears between the message and the button?

Comment: You can't, because that is part of this look and feel.

Comment: Perhaps [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) to see if that helps you.